# Django Shell shortcut in Windows

Tags: python, django, command-line, windows-xp, batch-file

I'm trying to write a bat file so I can quickly launch into the Interactive Shell for one of my Django projects.

Basically I need to write a python script that can launch "manage.py shell" and then be able to print from mysite.myapp.models import *

The problem is manage.py shell cannot take additional arguments and launching into "manage.py shell" exits the parent script, so I am unable to then execute additional commands.

Comment: What does "then be able to print from mysite.myapp.models import *" mean?

Comment: What you want is an equivalent of "python manage.py shell" in Windows? Correct me if I am wrong. I dint even know that doesnt work, by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First download django-extensions from google code. search for "django command-extensions"

Download and install it by running setup.py install from within the folder (it has a file called "setup.py")
You will then be able to run manage.py shell_plus instead of manage.py shell, giving you an enhanced version of the python shell which will load all your models automatically

Now the batch file:
make a new file "run_django.bat" on your desktop (for instance), then enter to it

```
@echo off
cd [path/to/project]
manage.py shell_plus
```

save the file. anytime you click it, it will start your shell with all your models loaded